# Django: How to automatically restart gunicorn after my code changed

Tags: django, gunicorn, restart

I'm developing a Django website, in which top menu should reflect changes in the page structure. In some sections (such as "About") changes are rare, so the menu is kept as a separate HTML file, which is included into the base template base.html:

```
{% include "includes/menu_about.html" %}
```

Although this works, there is a problem: the server doesn´t "see" that my menu_about.html file has changed, and, apparently, shows the page from cash, so the user doesn´t see the updated menu until I manually restart Gunicorn server.

How is it possible to solve this problem? Looks like I have to make Gunicorn to restart automatically each time after my "Page" model saved. Perhaps, there is certain command in Django, which can be run on model save and restart the Gunicorn? Or may be certain settings in the Gunicorn itself?

Comment: That's how it is or it should be. Gunicorn is a production grade server, so any changes due to any reason should not affect gunicorn or restart it. If you want to have your changes reflected immediately, then it is better to use development server `django runserver` command, but it should not be in a production environment.

Comment: @ruddra, OK then. What I pass this html code from my UpdateView to the template as a context variable? In this case Gunicorn should show up-to-date content...

Comment: You can do that, if you think it is a good idea.

Comment: you have to install Supervisor, that is what is for, to restart gunicorn every time there are changes. I can't believe nobody has said it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using it already, you can use the [`--reload`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=reload#reload) flag of Gunicorn. You may need to tweak [`reload-extra-files`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=reload#reload-extra-files) as well.

If you still have issues, it might be related to Django, which caches templates. Make sure you are not using the [Cached loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader)